# In fabric 2 how to run a diffent user?

Tags: python, fabric

I wish to use fabric 2 for doing things on my server as a different user then the one I am logging into.

### Example:

```
from fabric import Connection, Config

HOST = 'myserver'
sudo_pass = 'mypassword'
config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': sudo_pass}})

c = Connection(HOST, config=config)
c.run('whoami')
c.sudo('whoami')
with c.sudo('su ceres'):
    c.run('whoami')
```

### Output:

```
myname
[sudo] password: root
[sudo] password:
```

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, you can either specify a user kwarg, or modify config:

```
from fabric import Connection, Config

HOST = 'myserver'
sudo_user = 'ceres'
sudo_pass = 'mypassword'
config = Config(
    overrides={
        'sudo': {
            'user': sudo_user,
            'password': sudo_pass
        }
    }
)

c = Connection(HOST, config=config)
c.run('whoami')
c.sudo('whoami')
c.sudo('whoami', user='root')
```

Which looks like this:

```
myname
[sudo] password: ceres
[sudo] password: root
```

Comment: Thanks. One additional question: Is this documented somewhere or do I have to dig through the code to find such solutions?

Comment: I didn't look at the code to answer this, just the sections of the Invoke docs that discussed Context and Config objects.  Connection objects in Fabric are just Invoke Context objects with a little extra SSH sprinkled on top.